# How to setup a conditional cron job in raspbian

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, cron

```
If (SYSTEM_IP != SOME_IP)
       sudo openvpn client.ovpn
ELSE
       exit
```

Frequency - every 5 minutes
To be executed in a linux shell

I need this task as my raspberry pi may lose the internet connection for several hours which disconnects it from openvpn server. I am not allowed to edit openvpn connection configuration file, I tried to set up a cron job which connects my machine to the server every five minutes, but I want to optimize it using the conditional statements.

This job should run every 5 minutes on my raspi, if ip address of the pi is not equal to the given ip, it means that pi is not connected to my private network on openvpn server, so it should connect to the openvpn server using sudo openvpn client.ovpn command else it should exit from the cron job.

I would also appreciate if you have any other way to check if the board is connected to openvpn if not then connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cron jobs must be all one line, so

```
/5 * * * * ip addr show | fgrep --quiet SOME_IP || sudo openvpn client.ovpn
```

every 5 minutes `/5 * * * *`

crond runs `ip addr show` and passes the output to 
`fgrep`

`fgrep` checks for `SOME_IP` in the  `ip addr show` output

If it's not found `fgrep` returns 1 and `||` causes `sudo openvpn client.ovpn` to be run

Comment: Hey @Jasen, Just tried this `ip addr show | fgrep --quiet xx.xx.xxx.xx || sudo openvpn client.ovpn` as a plain command, its running `sudo openvpn client.ovpn` everytime

Comment: Managed with php script
**task.php**
`<?php 
 if(file_get_contents("https://www.kekarjawalekar.com/ip.php") == "xx.xx.xxx.xx") {
  print("Already Connected\n");
 }
 else {
  print("Starting Connection Procedure \n");
  
  shell_exec("sudo openvpn client.ovpn");
  
 }
 
?>`

/5 * * * * sudo php task.php

Comment: what Michiel says: `If it runs openvpn every time, that means fgrep is not seeing the ip you're listing in the output of ip addr show` - try `ip addr show | fgrep xx.xx.xxx.xx`  does it say anything?

Comment: @json sorry it did work, I was trying with my public ip which was not listed in ip addr show